# how do i detect key combinations in python from the background in linux?

Tags: python, linux

what I am trying to do is to make a script running in the background, and when I press a key combination(for example Fn + w) another script is executed.

If this is very hard to do in python I could do it in an other one, or if anyone knows another way to do this.

I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with XFCE.

Comment: Something like a keylogger? [Evdev.py](http://svn.navi.cx/misc/trunk/python/evdev/evdev.py) its got most of the keys mapped out. Also check out the contents of /dev/input/event* on your system.

Comment: thank you, ill see if i can get that to work.

Comment: Really? Or are you trying to create a malware or something? :D I've spied my school network, the password was 1234!!! LOL

Comment: lol, no im not trying to create a malware. actually I just want to get Fn + w to trigger "s"(temporary fix to a bad key, tired of using a onboard keyboard for "s") :p

Answer (score 0):

there is existing a python library named python-xlib. You can catch keys and do something on your system 
http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/

here is an example code, a server receives keycode over the network and press it:

```
import Xlib.display
import Xlib.X
import Xlib.XK
import Xlib.protocol.event
import Xlib.ext.xtest
import socket, sys


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
keycode = None
try:
        s.bind(("", 49999))
        i=0
        display = Xlib.display.Display()

        while True:
                daten, addr = s.recvfrom(1024)
                if (daten != 'ende'):
                        keycode = daten
                if keycode == '111' or keycode == '116':
                        print '%d up/down' % i
                        Xlib.ext.xtest.fake_input(display, Xlib.X.KeyPress, int(keycode) )
                        display.sync()
                if keycode == '117':
                        # A
                        Xlib.ext.xtest.fake_input(display, Xlib.X.KeyPress, int(
keycode) )
                        display.sync()
                if keycode == '118':
                        # Y
                        Xlib.ext.xtest.fake_input(display, Xlib.X.KeyPress, int(keycode) )
                        display.sync()
                if keycode == '119':
                        # SPACE
                        Xlib.ext.xtest.fake_input(display, Xlib.X.KeyPress, int(keycode) )
                        display.sync()
                if daten == 'ende':
                        if keycode != None:
                                Xlib.ext.xtest.fake_input(display, Xlib.X.KeyRelease, int(keycode) )
                                keycode = None
                                display.sync()
                        daten = None
                        continue

finally:
        s.close()
```

Comment: would this work with out a server? when i tested to run it it just froze. i assume the evdev.py is the way to do what i want but haven't figured how it works yet.

Comment: This server thing is an example.  It runs without it. if you start the script, it listen to the input. You can try what is better for you. For job like this, i use xlib, evdev.py i dont try it